Vitest VS Code extension displaying 0% code coverage
When running vitest run --coverage, I am seeing code coverage that accurately represents the coverage I have added via unit tests.

However, when pressing the "Run Tests with Coverage" button through VS Code's Vitest extension, it's showing 0% code coverage for everything.

For further information, I am using a vite.config.ts that contains my Vite and my Vitest configuration, rather than dedicated vite.config.ts and vitest.config.ts configurations:
// vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig(() => {
    // ...
    test: {
      environment: 'jsdom',
      coverage: {
        provider: 'istanbul'
      },
      globals: true
    }
}

And this vite.config.ts lives at the root of my repository at the same level as my package.json, so it should presumably be shared by the Vitest VS Code extension as well as when I run vitest run --coverage.
Here are some of the relevant bits from my package.json:
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/jsdom": "20.0.1",
    "@types/node": "18.19.34",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "5.0.5",
    "@vitest/coverage-istanbul": "2.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "9.27.0",
    "jsdom": "20.0.3",
    "vite": "5.3.1",
    "vitest": "2.0.4"
  }
}


Why is there a discrepancy when I run vitest run --coverage via CLI versus when I use "Run Tests with Coverage" through VS Code's Vitest extension?
